# Проблема с регистрацией приложения в Instagram

Tags: instagram

Добрый день! 
Не удается получить апрув в инстаграме. Нужен апрув на разрешения: likes, public content and followers list.

**В методе выбираю:** My product helps brands and advertisers understand, manage their audience and media rights.

**В API use case:**
Our application is a platform of social networks. We want to collect information about our brand and our company in our platform. Users will be aware of all our events in the social networks of the company in one application. Our application will helps us to manage our audience.

Our application doesn't use the Instagram APIs to replicate or attempt to replace the functionality or essential user experiences of Instagram.com or any of Instagram's apps.
Also application complies Platform Policy  Instagram. Application doesn't enable bulk actions and/or automated actions, because the application will be used only by the target audience of our brand.

**В итоге, уже 3-ий раз приходит один и тот же ответ от Инстаграма:**
Invalid Use Case: The use case described in your submission notes, screencast and website is not a valid use case. If you are trying to build analytics for personal use or one-off projects, note that we do not support one-off and single use projects. We recommend that you use a third-party platform that powers this use case. If you are building a platform for this use case, we will only approve one client ID for all your integrations. For more information, please see: https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/

Писал в поддержку, ответа так и не получил. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?